# How can I prioritize search country in Bing Maps Ajax

Tags: ajax, search, bing-maps

In current realization I just add country to query, but this logic is incorrect.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/'
        + searchString + ' ' + currentCountry + '?c=' + currentCulture + ...,
        dataType: 'script'
    });
```

But if I try to search city out of currentCountry, I will find currentCountry, but not searchString .

```
Example: searchString = Boston, currentCountry = Australia
```

Second approach - remove currentCountry from query at all, but it will cause another bug.
I will not find less famous place in currentCountry

```
Example: searchString = Moscow, currentCountry = USA.
```

Result of this query will be - Moscow, Russia and not Moscow, Washington, D.C.

Is there some ability to specify search country?
First try of search will be in currentCountry, if it fails, then second will be in all World.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Find a Location by Address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701714.aspx) you could get the latitude and longitude coordinates based on a set of address values for **specific countries**.

Example:

The query:

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/US/Moscow?o=xml&key=BingMapsKey
```

> Note: A structured URL specifies the location data for the country
>   (US in this example) as part of the URL path.

will return locations for `Moscow` situated in United States.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the best practices for Bing Maps it actually recommends using the unstructured URL format rather than the structured format when geocoding as it will increase the accuracy of the results: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn894107.aspx

In order to limit the results to a single country, simple append the country to the query.

Your code is close but there should be a comma, and you would be using the query parameter as the format you are using is meant for reverse geocoding coordinates. Here is a modified version of your code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q='
        + encodeURIComponent(searchString + ', ' + currentCountry) + '?c=' + currentCulture + ...,
        dataType: 'script'
    });
```

You also want to encode the query value to ensure that special characters do not cause any issues.

Comment: I want to search in current country and if there are no any results, then to search all over the world. Adding of currentCountry in the query will break this logic, won't it?

Comment: If you want it to search both the current country will limit the results to a single country. If there are no results you would need to make a second call to search the whole world. Alternatively, you could always leave out the country and just search the whole world from the beginning and have the maximum results and the country ISO returned and then search through the results for those that have the country ISO you want.

Comment: First approach always will return australia for query = "singaphore, australia", Second is better, but it need additional actions from my side. Vadim's solution didn't have any visible problems

Comment: For the first approach you can look at the entity type of the result. If it is a CountryRegion, then ignore it. Vadim's solution will limit you to a single country and will never search the whole world. It is also using a structure that is not recommended in the best practices for Bing Maps as it returns less accurate results than using the query version of the URL.